# IIS & Apache on same machine diffrent ip's

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, iis

I have a server with Windows 2008 Server on, and we host some ASP.NET apps and some php.
The problem is that PHP under IIS dose not work 100% correctly under IIS (At least not as i would under an apache server) and this is giving us problems.
So as the server has multiple ip where we thinking if i user ip 1 would i hit the IIS server, but if i use ip 2 would i hit the Apache server. Where i go in by port 80 on both.
Maby having apache running on port 8080 or something and use some kind of software router to direct it to port 8080, if a users enters in ip2:80?

Is this possible? and if how so? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely have both of them in the same machine, of course I would suggest using IIS for running PHP (using FastCGI and WinCache for getting a much better performance than with other server).

I dont know much about Apache, but in IIS you can go to the Bindings (Server->Sites->Site right-click -> Edit Bindings) and edit the http/80 to specifically only bind to the IP address that you want it to listen. 
My thinking is that Apache will have something similar.

Alternatively you could also use ARR (http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) which is an IIS extension that will allow you to Proxy requests to other ports, or even other machines if you needed to in an incredibly performant way, with features like Disk Caching and many others that would be very useful.

Comment: Thank you, the reason we can't user IIS for some of our php is because one the pages we are hosting dose not work well on it "Wordpress" gets a countless number og error 500 on iss, and uploadeing in wordpress is not working :(